# Bootstrap: Format <form> inside drop down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, phoenix-framework

In the Phoenix framework, if I create a delete button (using the `link` helper function) then it generates a form element.

However, if I put this code inside a Bootstrap drop down, then it's not rendered as a menu item.

I tried using the `:form` parameter to remove the "button" class, like so:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  <li><a href="#">Insert above</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Insert below</a></li>
  <li role="separator" class="divider" />
  <li><%= link "Delete", to: log_path(@conn, :delete, log), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], form: [class: ""] %></li>
</ul>
```

This didn't help much. When I inspected the element using Chrome, it seems that Bootstrap menus are looking for the css selection - `.dropdown-menu>li>a`

Is there another class I could take advantage of for the form? What's the best way to address this with Bootstrap?